# Sequence of Action Method Call is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery

I am trying to save the form automatically whenever user switches tab.

I just call Save action method whenever user tries to navigate out from the current form.

It works fine most of the time. But rarely, the Save action method is called after calling the Index method of clicked tab controller. Thus, my entity object sent from View to Controller to Save is lost and becomes NULL.

For example:

- I have two tabs (Home & Admin)
- I enter details in Home and leave Home by clicking Admin tab.
- It should call Save method in Home Controller first before calling
  Index in Admin Controller. It works most of the time. But rarely,
  Index in Admin Controller is called before Save method in Home is
  called.

The order of statements as below. I have no clue what is going wrong here. Can you please help? Thank you.

Step 1:

> $.ajax({
>                       url: urlSave,
>                       type: 'POST',
>                       data: formData
>                   });

Step 2:

> window.location.href = getBaseURL() + "Admin"

I would be glad to you if you throw some light on it. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should navigate to the new url in the callback of the ajax call so that it will execute after the ajax call is done.

Use the `success` event and inside that you can have the code which loads the new page content.

```
$.ajax({ url: urlSave,
         type: 'POST',
          data: loiFormData,
          success:function(response){
            //this code will execute once ajax request succeeds
             window.location.href = getBaseURL() + "Admin"
      });
 });
```

Comment: Can I ask you one more question related to it? I would like to have a anchor tag with href url rather having window.location.href statement. How to handle callback in this scenario because href will be called before Ajax call is made. Thanks for ur help.